# Android - do I need transparent images for header, or with text already on the images?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create a header navigation for my app.  I want to get rid of spaces between the buttons, and as I understand it, I need to set images as the background.

My question is whether the images should contain the text on them, or be transparent, and I would just put the text on the buttons by the text field in the layout of that button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it both ways, but I'd recommend setting the text on the images it saves you space and allows more room for change in case you wanna change a word you dont have to edit the image.

And most importantly you let android auto scale you text to fit screen size( if you set to sp of course )

Comment: thanks...I was also thinking something similar.  Btw, what are the common image dimansions for the background images to make? Should they be squares? Or rectangles? How will android adjust them? Thanks!